# Как при сериализации через DataContract избавиться от поля "__type"

Tags: json, asp.net, wcf, сериализация

Каким образом можно избавиться от поля "__type" в ответе запроса? Данное поле появляется из-за использования атрибута KnownType, но не понятно как его убрать

```
[KnownType(nameof(GetKnownTypes))]
    
    [DataContract]
    public class ContactData
    {
        [DataMember(Name = nameof(GivenName))]
        public string GivenName { get; set; }

        public static List<Type> DerivedTypes = new List<Type>{typeof(ContactData)};
        static IEnumerable<Type> GetKnownTypes()
        {
            return DerivedTypes;
        }

    }

    [DataContract]
    public class ContactDataV2 : ContactData
    {
        [DataMember(Name = nameof(Surname))]
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        static ContactDataV2()
        {
            DerivedTypes.Add(typeof(ContactDataV2));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Если его убрать, то перестанет сохраняться информация о полиморфных объектах и сериализация сломается. / Покажите код используемых классов-моделей.

Comment: Как можно адекватнее вставить код? Картинку нельзя, а если вставлять текстом, то ерунда получается

Comment: Вставьте код в вопрос. Его можно редактировать.

Comment: Ну вот смотрите. По ссылке `ContactData` могут лежать объекты как `ContactData`, так и `ContactDataV2`. Как их различить в сериализованном потоке? Нужна какая-то дополнительная метаинформация. Ей и является поле `__type`. Не надо его убирать! Пусть будет.

Comment: Меня всегда интересовало, зачем люди пытаются лезть руками в стандартизированные протоколы? Есть сервис, он выставляет своё описание в виде wsdl. По нему автоматически генерируется клиент. И начинается общение между клиентом и сервисом. Всё происходит автоматически, под капотом. Почему кого-то должно волновать наличие какого-то поля?

Comment: Просто я думал, что на моменте стерилизации можно это поле не выводить в ответе. Пусть оно будет, но не в ответе

Comment: Давайте с начала. Сервер выдал информацию. Клиент её принял. По наличию этого поля клиент сможет понять, что ему послали: `ContactData` или `ContactDataV2`. Без этого поля он этого не поймёт!

Comment: Надеюсь вы действительно используете WCF? Или только огрызок этой технологии: DataContractSerializer? / Как вы на клиенте обрабатываете полученную информацию: с помощью кода, автоматически сгенерированного по wsdl? Или вручную наколбасили?

Comment: И что является клиентом: javascript на странице в браузере? Судя по метке asp.net.

Comment: Да, клиентом является страница в браузере на javascript, поэтому там без разницы как обрабатывать и какой там тип

Comment: Тогда зачем вы взяли wcf? Ладно. / Покажите кусочек кода C#, который делает сериализацию.